Access Heroku config vars from CI
I'm trying to set up testing with Heroku CI on a Flask app. My tests reference environment variables, which I have set as config vars in Heroku. However, the tests are failing because they can't see these environment variables.
I would like the tests to run successfully, with access to the environment variables.
Here's my app.json:
{
  "name": "my-heroku-app-name",
  "repository": "https://github.com/myorg/myrepo",
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "scripts": {
        "test-setup": "pip install -r requirements.txt",
        "test": "pytest tests"
      }
    }
  }
}

Here's the failure I see:
mytest.py:71: in <module>
    assert ENVIRONMENT in ALL_ENVS
E   AssertionError

I tried adding this in my app.json:
  "env": {
    "ENVIRONMENT": {
      "required": true
    },
  },

But then the CI failed to run, with the following error:
Could not create test run. Invalid app.json. Config var "ENVIRONMENT" is required.

I have verified that the config var is set, with heroku config:get ENVIRONMENT --app my-heroku-app-name.
Maybe I need to specify the value of the variable in app.json, but how? I don't want to include raw strings there, because some of the variables are sensitive.
The Heroku docs don't specify how to do this.

It looks like you'll have to configure those variables for your CI pipeline independently of your main config vars:

Note that unlike review apps, Heroku CI does not inherit any config vars from the parent app.
To set confidential or volatile environment variables (such as access tokens) that you shouldn’t include in app.json, you can instead add them to your pipeline’s Heroku CI settings in the Heroku Dashboard:

Values specified here are available in all test runs.

If you'd prefer to do this via the command line you can use heroku ci:config:set, e.g.
heroku ci:config:set SOME_VAR=some-value


That's so helpful, thank you! Do you know if there is any way to ensure that the CI app config vars stay in sync with the parent app? Or is it necessarily to update them manually?

@Richard, unfortunately I think that needs to be done manually. If you want them to always change in lock-step maybe you could write a script that calls both heroku config:set (for the app) and heroku ci:config:set (for the pipeline)? Or have a scheduled job that reads your production config and sets your pipeline config? Though there are advantages to keeping them separate. For example, should your tests talk to your production database? Should they use your production API keys?
